# Sort student array according to average marks

Tags: c#

I have created student class array in C# like this

```
var Student = new Student[5];
```

having variables `sid,name, avgMrks;`
I want to sort array according to average marks of all the students.

Answer (score 3):

I assuming when you say having variables, you mean that the Student object has the properties: sid, name, avgMrks.  You can do:

```
Student.OrderBy (x=>x.avgMrks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ

```
Student = Student.OrderByDescending(c => c.avgMrks).ToArray();
```

It returns IOrderedIEnumerable, which you can convert back to Array if you want.

Or

```
string[] ArrStr = new string[] { "A", "A2", "A1" };    
Array.Sort(ArrStr);    
Array.Reverse(ArrStr);
```